# Request header wont be added

Tags: angular, http, ionic-framework, header, request

I have an issue with sending the token authentication to the server, i'm adding the token as shown:

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Authorization', token);

let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

return this.http.get(path, {headers: headers}).map(response => response.json());
```

i add the Authorization header to the request, it should be straight forward, but when i check the  **Request headers** in the Browser the Authorization header is not there!

it looks like this:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:authorization
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Connection:keep-alive
Host:192.168.1.117:3000
Origin:http://localhost:8100
Referer:http://localhost:8100/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 9_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/601.1.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Mobile/13B143 Safari/601.1
```

so i don't have an Authorization header, instead i have a  **Access-Control-Request-Headers** with value  **authorization**.

any ideas about his weird behavior?

Comment: Is this request going back to to the same server that served the Angular app, or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I successfully send my headers when making GET requests via an Ionic app I am building ..

```
import { Headers, Http } from "@angular/http"
```

And then ..

```
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Authorization', token);     

this.http.get('https://api.domain.com/call', {headers:headers}).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
    // data                                                                      
});
```

I don't use `RequestOptions`

Actually, to be precise my line that sets the Auth header is actually ...

```
headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
```